# How hard does The Flash punch?

Tags: dc, the-flash

I am going to simplify this question and not make a massive physics explanation here.

Few things to know:

- Mass is locked up energy we call "inertial mass". When we speak of an object's mass increasing due to acceleration, we are really talking about its inertial mass increasing.
- So when we think of mass as energy, we can begin to understand why an object will increase its ‘mass’ as it speeds up. As an object increases in speed, so does the amount of energy that it has, this energy is what we refer to as "the increase in mass".
- The energy of a particle diverges to infinity as it approaches the speed of light. Since we can never have infinite energy for a particle, the speed of light cannot be reached.
- Since an object has infinite kinetic energy when it approaches the speed of light, it therefore has infinite mass as well.

So to simplify due to Einstein's "Theory of Relativity" the faster you go, the higher your mass becomes, which is the reason why we will never be able to travel at the speed of light.

But in the case of The Flash he can travel at the speed of light, which means unless the Theory of Relativity is a non existing factor in the DC universe. A punch from Flash will have INFINITE power behind the punch and that would destroy the universe if he ever did this.

I have not read everything Flash or Flash related, and this question comes from a discussion i had with fellow physic students. i'll try and rephrase the question.

So how hard can he actually hit?
When Flash used a The Infinite Mass Punch, has he ever destroyed a universe or obliterated an opponent to atoms?.

Comment: The Flash (depending on which one) can travel wayyyyyyy faster than the speed of light. And he literally has something called **The Infinite Mass Punch**, which, is essentially of infinite force.

Comment: I would suggest you to delete the last line from your question because asking if someone is the most powerful in the universe tends to be a broad question and also opinion based. In your case, which Flash are you referring to (Garrick, Barry, Wally)? Which universe (Pre-52, new-52, rebirth, etc)

Comment: Which flash is irrelevant unless there are a flash that can't move with the speed of light. with infinite force behind a punch of something as small as a flash's hand should "potentially" create a black hole when he does The Infinite Mass punch. If not all out send a ripple effect through out the infinite universes that destroys them all. by definition Infinite is Inifite.. there is no limited to the force he does when he punch's a person while moving at the speed of light.

Comment: Hitting superman with infinite force would blow even a ''superhero'' like superman to atomic particles.

Comment: @Jenayah that thread speaks of his strength. not how hard he can punch. as force is not reliant of strength this does not answer my question :/

Comment: I think you might be over complicating this waaaay too much. Comics take liberties with physics, obviously, so trying to apply real world physics is never going to work.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot you may be correct. i thought it an interesting question from physics student point of view. As the DC universe still ''beside'' the superheros takes place in our ordinary world and the laws of physics that applys in ours applys to the ordinary people there ;)

Comment: “I am going to simplify this question and not make a massive physics explanation here” — _[proceeds to talk about physics quite a lot]_

Comment: @PaulD.Waite that was the short version, i wanted to throw in a lot of calculations to back up the statement. but thought that might be overkill. so a simple explanation is what you got :)

Comment: @Holmberg aren't we lucky.

Comment: @Holmberg Jay Garrick doesn't travel at the speed of light